# Flex direction column and fill screen width

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, frontend

I have a list of elements of varying height and want to lay them out such that the full screen width gets filled (but not overflown with a horizontal scrollbar):

[image]

How can I accomplish this via CSS? I cannot simply switch to `flex-direction: row` as there would be large gaps between rows due to the varying heights of the elements.

Here is my hacky attempt via JS:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-joliot-9n3woy?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const BOX_WIDTH = 200;
const boxHeights = [...Array(500)].map(() => Math.random() * 100);

export default function App() {
  const ref = React.useRef();

  const [originalHeight, setOriginalHeight] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!originalHeight && ref.current?.clientHeight) {
      setOriginalHeight(ref.current?.clientHeight);
    }
  }, [originalHeight, ref.current?.clientHeight]);

  const [height, setHeight] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (originalHeight && ref.current?.clientWidth) {
      setHeight(
        originalHeight / Math.floor(ref.current?.clientWidth / BOX_WIDTH) / 0.9
      );
    }
  }, [ref.current?.clientWidth, originalHeight]);

  return (
    <>
      <div
        ref={ref}
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: "column",
          flexWrap: "wrap",
          ...(height && { height })
        }}
      >
        {[...Array(500)].map((_, i) => (
          <div
            style={{
              border: "solid",
              width: BOX_WIDTH,
              height: boxHeights[i],
              margin: "10px"
            }}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: So what's the problem with this attempt? Flowing columns is what came to mind for me as well. Really, CSS problems should be presented as HTML, not JavaScript. It's not easy for anyone to experiment or demonstrate a solution this way.

Comment: What you're looking for is a masonry layout, which there are many solutions available out there for it already.

Comment: @isherwood it's not completely reliable because the columns will not use up the whole height due to the irregular heights, hence we could create more columns than the screen permits.